How to disable an HP laptop ethernet port due to faulty LED indicator?
HP laptop with Windows 10. Ethernet LED indicator is faulty: it flashes constantly with a very bright light even when port is not in use. Sometimes whacking the laptop helps sometimes not.
Sure a black sticker may help but I'm sure such a bright light drains the battery faster.
I understand that disabling the light is probably not possible but since I mostly use Wi-Fi I would like to know if disabling the entire port will help and if so how to disable it?

You can disable network ports SOMETIMES in the BIOS, or in Windows in the Device Manager. If physical impact can change the behavior, the problem is likely a bad/faulty connection inside the laptop, and disassembling the laptop and inspecting and cleaning and reseating those connections is the best way to solve the root problem. LEDs use miniscule amounts of energy. While it does drain your battery more quickly, it will not be a significant or possibly even a measurable impact.

All that said, in order to give you more precise information, we need to know the specific model of your laptop. We also would benefit from knowing what research you have done and what you have tried yourself to disable this, prior to asking.

I think you are overestimating the power draw of the LED, but unless you are really looking for something to solder, I have to recommend either a piece of electrical tape, or take it to a professional for servicing. Don't be surprised if they want to replace the whole mainboard though.

I have used a dab of liquid electrical tape right on the spot when tape wasn't appropriate.

A very bright LED indicator might use 20 mA at 3 VDC, about 60 mW. If the machine has a 60 W power adapter, that LED would use only 1/1,000th as much power. Fell free to cover with black tape, nail-polish or anything else.

@DrMoishe Pippik's comment "that LED would use only 1/1,000th as much power" is the right answer, but I guess you did ask how to stop it anyway.
I actually tested this on my HP laptop (that I can dual boot into Windows 10), and this is how you can do it with device manager:

Hit Windows+X and choose device manager, or just search for it.
In the “Network adapters” section select your ethernet adapter (usually called something like “Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller”) and press disable at the control tab at the top:



flahing continues also after disabling controller

@grunt well it sure worked for me... maybe for you it does need to be turned off in somewhere 'deeper' than the OS (e.g. the BIOS/UEFI.) But is was worth a shot, right?
